# Cannot remove Nuvola Player 1.0.5

Tags: 13.04, uninstall

I have tried purge and removal commands as well as complete removal from packages but this version will just not go away. It now says when I try to remove from the command line that the software is not installed and so no need to remove.

I don't know what the problem is. I read that it might be because it was installed from a zip file.

Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This, from the developer, Jiří Janoušek, helped answer my question:

You have probably installed Nuvola Player from source code. If you have
the source directory still on your hard disk, you should run "sudo ./waf
uninstall" from that directory. If not, you have to remove Nuvola
Player's directories and files manually. Command "find / -name
nuvolaplayer" should help you to locate them.

Answer (score 0):

To remove all user data of Nuvola Player, use command:

```
rm -rfv $HOME/.local/share/nuvolaplayer $HOME/.config/nuvolaplayer $HOME/.cache/nuvolaplayer
```

Comment: I did, but it did not uninstall it. I tried purging and "autoremoving" afterwards and no luck.

Comment: I would appreciate any more help with this.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install synaptic`
Search for the package and nuvolaplayer files. Remove them.

Comment: Yes, I've definitely tried that as well without success. It's very strange.

Comment: Does anyone else have an idea on how to make sure there is no trace of an app left? I don't know why this is being so difficult. Like I said, I think it might have been installed from a "zip" file.

Answer (score 0):

Install synaptic package manager

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

Open Synaptic Package Manager

Then search for `novola` and mark them for removal and finally click on Apply.